# Listen port on network 3g model sim?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

I have a modem 3G sim add computer access internet. i want use c# listen port 50000.
example :

```
 TcpListener tcpServerListener = new TcpListener(50000);
            tcpServerListener.Start(); //start server
```

How i can access port 50000 on over internet.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what IP-address has your device, where the program runs. Then you must use any TCP-client that can connect to a network port, for example `netcat` or `telnet`.

```
$ nc 1.2.3.4 50000
$ telnet 1.2.3.4 50000
```

Here you must write real IP address instead of 1.2.3.4.

Of course this connection makes nothing useful — you just checks if it is possible to connect to your server or not.

Comment: I use: 

   TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ServerIp, 50000);
                Console.WriteLine(client.Connected);
Console write:
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 27.69.151.228:50000

Comment: Can you try with netcat or telnet to be sure that the port is really open?

Comment: what i want is open port 50000 on model 3G sim network. what with ADSL just need add NAT port is can access over network.